Looker Studio Data Blend for Multi-step SPA Quiz Visualization
I need your help with the Looker Studio data blend.
I have a GA4 property collecting data for my specific User Journey. It's already connected with Looker Studio, and I've already completed most of the visualizations I need.
A brief overview of the User Journey: it's a multi-step SPA Quiz. The question step view event looks like this:
{
  event: 'question_2',
  question_text: 'Lorem Ipsum?', // can be 1-3 variants of any questions based on the previous answer
  answers_count: 3, // number of possible answers
};

The answer step event looks like this:
{
  event: 'question_2_answer',
  answer_text: 'my answer 1', // 2-4 possible answers for each question
};

I want to create a simple bar visualization for the answers with two filters:

First filter: choose a question-answer pair number.
Second filter: after choosing the first filter, select a question
under this number.

The bar chart should then show the possible answers for the specific chosen question.
I'm finding this difficult because the question parameter is associated with one event, and the answer parameter is associated with another event. I'm not very skilled in blending data, and I need your advice. Thank you.
